# I need to add top-margin to caption of elementor widget

Tags: html, css, text, margin, elementor

I would like to apply a top-margin to a caption of my widget through custom CSS feature in Elementor.

[image: screenshot of what it looks like on website]

Right now my code works in the way that it applies margin to the whole widget.

```
selector { margin-top: 50px !important; }
```

If I change it to:

```
h4 { margin-top: 50px !important; }
```

It applies style to the h4 of the whole page, but not to this caption, even though it has h4 html tag.

I could also give my widget a css class, so other h4 on this page wouldn't be affected, but it still doesn't add margin to the caption itself.

Comment: Live URL, please?

Comment: This could be caused by [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) but it is impossible to tell without any code.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on your screenshot, there is no other h4 element on this widget.

So that you can add margin only this widget h4 element which is an image caption.

Here is the code for setting the margin on the caption.

```
selector h4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

or

selectorh4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Put this CSS on this widget custom CSS field.

This code works only for this widget h4 element.